# How to resolve the problem of this code? The ability to receive all values to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, laravel-5

I have validated it to send one or two or all three if the user checks the checkbox. My problem is I only receive one value even if the user checks all three.

This is is on laravel php framework, but I think it applies to all database logic.

This is MySQL data type

$table->string('category');

```js
     function restorative() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("restorative").required;
                               
                      }

                    function esthetics() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("esthetics").required;
                               
                      }
                      function implant() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("implant").required;
                               
                      }
```

```html
   <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Restorative" id="restorative" onclick="restorative()"><label for="">Restorative</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Esthetics" id="esthetics" onclick="esthetics()"><label for="">Esthetics</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Implants" id="implants" onclick="esthetics()"><label for="">Implants</label>
```

Comment: Use an array with `name="category[]"` then you will have a `$_POST['category']` array in PHP.

Comment: I get an error of Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException of Array to string conversion

Comment: Abra's comment is right, then in Laravel, you can access the data with `request('category')`

Comment: I get an error as stated before your answer. I am receiving  "array to string conversion error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array with name="category[]" then you will have a $_POST['category'] then before save use json_encode($_POST['category']) which covert array to string. Later you can json_decode($data) to get original array. Thanks